# Why is this returning a generators list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, generator

I'm a beginner python user. 
I'm trying to define a function for 'smoothing' a list of floats by averaging the components over a number of neighbours.

Here my code:

```
import random

random.seed(1)

def moving_window_average(x, n_neighbors=1):
    width = n_neighbors*2 + 1
    y = list()
    for i in range(n):
        y.append(sum(x[i+t])/width for t in range(-n_neighbors,n_neighbors))
    return y


x=[0,10,5,3,1,5]
avg=moving_window_average(x, 1)
print(avg)
```

In output I get what appears to be a list of 'generators', something which i don't know ad was not expecting.
In particular:

```
[<generator object moving_window_average.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f57f992aba0>, <generator object moving_window_average.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f57f992ab48>, <generator object moving_window_average.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f57f992a728>, <generator object moving_window_average.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f57f992aa98>, <generator object moving_window_average.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f57f992aa40>, <generator object moving_window_average.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f57f992a9e8>]
```

Can someone point me towards what is happening here?

Thanks you a lot

Comment: how do you want to handle the *"corners"*?

Comment: i'm trying to treat the list as 'circular' using negative indeces

Comment: The code in your question is unrunnable—`n` is undefined.

Comment: You are right.. I was messing with code for a while and deleted the function line `n = len(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the expression you have for "smoothing" the data is written incorrectly—so it evaluates to something called a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). I think the code below is the right way to express it:

```
import random

random.seed(1)
n = 3

def moving_window_average(x, n_neighbors=1):
    width = n_neighbors*2 + 1
    y = list()
    for i in range(n):
        y.append(sum(x[i+t] for t in range(-n_neighbors,n_neighbors)) / width)
    return y


x=[0,10,5,3,1,5]
avg=moving_window_average(x, 1)
print(avg)
```

Comment: thanks you a lot my friend, your code is working well and the link from the documentation was really clear, maybe i had to check it first :)

Comment: also, any idea why the following line in function definition for loop would result in a type error? `y.append([sum(x[i+t])/width for t in range(-n_neighbors,n_neighbors)])` @martineau

Comment: deppep: It could be because one (or more) items in argument `x` aren't integers.

Answer (score 0):

A generator is an iterable that is exhausted as it is iterated over. This is what you are creating with the statement `sum(x[i+t])/width for t in range(-n_neighbors,n_neighbors)`. If what you want is a list of lists, the correct statement would be `[sum(x[i+t])/width for t in range(-n_neighbors,n_neighbors)]`, which is instead a list comprehension. An inline generation of a list, so to say.

An article I found on the topic can be found [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/python-list-comprehensions-vs-generator-expressions-cef70ccb49db). Have a read.

Comment: I'm unable to test right now but will try asap and come back to you. thanks a lot for your help and the useful link

Answer (score 0):

you've encountered [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), which are integrated in comprehension list syntax but cause numberous mistake.

as example :

```
x=[0,10,5,3,1,5]

 (y for y in x) 
Out[19]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000000C02FEB8>

 [y for y in x]
Out[20]: [0, 10, 5, 3, 1, 5]

 print(y for y in x)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000000C02FE60>

 print((y for y in x))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000000BFA1938>

 print(*(y for y in x))
0 10 5 3 1 5

 [(y for y in x)]
Out[24]: [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000000BFA1D58>]

 list(y for y in x)
Out[25]: [0, 10, 5, 3, 1, 5]
```

In your case, I think you can correct you problem by adding `[]` aroud your expression:

```
y.append([sum(x[i+t])/width for t in range(-n_neighbors,n_neighbors)])
```

`[]` will force the generator to evaluate the values. Generator are powerful object used to save memory and delay execution. il not your aim here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this already but get the following type error: `y.append([sum(x[i+t])/width for t in range(-n_neighbors,n_neighbors)]); TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`